# Two project files for vs2019 and vs2022 are "colliding"

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-4.8, project-conversion

I have a big solution with many projects, all of them in vs2019, .net framework 4.7.2
The plan is to upgrade to .net6 by creating a project file for vs2022, and then do some #if net46 to keep backward compatibility with .net framework 4.7.2, at least in a transition period.
This is working, kind of! Because this happens:

1. I open the vs2019 project file in vs2019, and it compiles fine.
2. Then I open the vs2022 project file in vs2022 and it compiles fine.
3. Now, if I re-run step 1, it fails. vs2019 now tell me this:

*Error  CS0433  The type 'PipeAccessRule' exists in both 'System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' and 'System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'*

It turns out vs2022 installed a few nuget packages, system.security.xyz. If I delete these nuget packages from the computer, vs2019 once again compiles my project.

Why are vs2019 'detecting' the system.securiy.xyz packages if I don't have a reference to them?! (In fact, the vs2019 project uses no nugets at all)

---

This might not have anything to do with it, but the vs2019 .csproj file format is the 'old' format, starting with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="15.0">
```

While vs2022 is using the newer format, starting with

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

The project has no build dependencies to other projects in the solution.

---

UPDATE:
We just found out two interesting things:

- If I close all instances of visual studio and open only vs2019, remove the obj-folder and recompile, it works. Not so if an instance of vs2022 is open.
- The .net framework project compiles fine in vs2022. The errors happens only in vs2019.

I think this solves the problem at the moment. Thank's David and Bagus for your comments, you led me down the correct path.

Comment: VS2022 should be able to open the .NET Framework 4.x projects just fine by the way.

Comment: `system.security.cryptography`? are you using `ProtectedData`? if so, .net 6 do some "restructuring" and puts some implementation separate, see [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/64101).

Comment: DavidG, I knew this, but tested opening it in vs2022 anyway. That revealed an interesting detail: It just works! Do you think it is some kind of bug in vs2019?